# Pop a value from a map using one lookup

Tags: go

How to implement in Go a function that pops a key from a map using just one lookup? This version does two lookups on the map:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := map[string]int{"a":1, "b":2}
    a, ok := m["a"]
    if ok {
        delete(m, "a")
    }
    fmt.Println(a, m)
}
```

I checked maybe `delete` returns the value of deleted key:

```
package main

func main() {
    m := map[string]int{"a":1, "b":2}
    println(delete(m, "a"))
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
prog.go:5: delete(m, "a") used as value
```

Comment: "Pop" is a typical operation of stacks/heaps. Maps are unordered; sets, if you will. Use [`container/heap`](http://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/) instead.

Comment: @tomwilde I mean `pop` as in [Python dicts](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop)

Answer (score 5):

Go doesn't have a `Pop` function for maps, so there will always be 2 operations, a index and a `delete`.

If you're worried about verbosity *and* performance, and small helper function like so would be inlined, so there's no extra runtime overhead to using it.

```
func pop(m map[string]int, key string) (int, bool) {
    v, ok := m[key]
    if ok {
        delete(m, key)
    }
    return v, ok
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for "will be inlined"? I'd be interested to read up on how the Go compiler finds candidates for inlining.

Comment: An article about inlining from 2020: https://dave.cheney.net/2020/04/25/inlining-optimisations-in-go